# MS CryptoAPI - Machine Keystore with Error 0x80090016 (NTE_BAD_KEYSET) with certreq created keys

Tags: c, openssl, cryptoapi

## Summary

I create a PKCS#10 CSR with [`certreq`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736326%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and have set the option `Exportable=TRUE`. This successfully creates a key under the location `REQUEST`. I also have a valid certificate with key in `MY`. If I try to access any one of them the CryptoAPI reports error code `0x80090016`.

Running under different access rights could not solve this problem so far.

## Goal

My goal is to get both the keys in `MY` and `REQUEST`. If I call `CryptAcquireContextA()` on any of those, it fails.

## System

Windows 7 x64

## Sample Source Code

My complete code looks like this:

```
hStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM_A, 0, 0, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, "REQUEST");
pCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR_A, "CERTIFICATE_SUBJECT", NULL);

CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCert, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, NULL, &len);
pinfo = (CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO *) malloc(len);
CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCert, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, pinfo, &len);

provname = wide_to_asc(pinfo->pwszProvName);
contname = wide_to_asc(pinfo->pwszContainerName);

if(!CryptAcquireContextA(&hCryptProv, contname, provname, pinfo->dwProvType, 0)) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: 0x%x\n", err);
}
CryptGetUserKey(hCryptProv, pinfo->dwKeySpec, &hUserkey);
```

This code is mostly copied from the *OpenSSL capi engine*. Since the engine failed, I created the smallest possible code to search the error.

## The error

If I run this, it fails with the output `Error: 0x80090016`. This means one of three things according to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238187):

- Key container does not exist.
- You do not have access to the key container.
- The Protected Storage Service is not running.

## What have I done so far?

- Started service "Protected Storage"
- Verified container exists with MMC & Certificate Snap-In for `Local Computer`
- Ran the same code on the User store in user context - it worked

### File System Permissions

After some googling, I tried to change permissions on the file system. I found the files by looking at the `contname` variable of my code and searching for the file. I changed permissions on them (more accurate, I changed permissions on the parent folder). While this fixed the issue for `MY`, it seems I cannot change it for `REQUEST`.

One note here is that my container for `MY` seems to be here:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-1650336054-1974872081-316617838-545102
```

For `REQUEST` I found it under a different address:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
```

I am not sure on the workings here so I cannot explain why it would put them in different locations (one being user centric, the other one a system folder). The `MY` store was created with a regular administrator prompt and the command `certreq -new inf_file.inf cert-csr.csr` and after I received my certificate, I issued `certreq -accept cert.pem`. Then I created a new csr with the same command.

### Different privilege levels

I tried to execute my program with the following privileges:

- my local user account
- admin prompt (cmd->start as administrator)
- nt authority\system (`whoami` output)

To recieve a service prompt, I executed `psexec.exe –ids cmd.exe` according to a tip from [MaaSters Center](http://www.maas360.com/maasters/forums/laptop-management/show/177/starting-a-process-in-system-context)

## Final words

Any help or guidance on how to further narrow this problem down will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem and it is a lot simpler than I thought. I was sure that I would receive an unambiguous container name and don't need to be more specific but `CryptAcquireContext` actually requires me to pass a flag `CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET`.

So my function call has to look like this:

```
CryptAcquireContextA(&hCryptProv, contname, provname, pinfo->dwProvType, CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET)
```

Unfortunately this is not supported by the OpenSSL engine, so you would have to alter it yourself in the engine.

Answer (score 0):

See MSDN: "A key container created without this flag by a user that is not an administrator can be accessed only by the user creating the key container and the local system account."

Complete details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379886(v=vs.85).aspx