# Why does CryptAcquireContext consistantly return 0 (zero) on some computers?

Tags: vba

So a while back I implemented my own MS Access VBA Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator (CSPRNG) by using a call to MS API for Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider. It spits out random bytes 0-255 (00000000-11111111) in a cryptographically secure fashion. The call is accomplished through several DLL function declarations (calling "advapi32.dll") in the VBA module.

The problem here is that my call to `CryptAcquireContext(...)` is NOT giving me a cryptographic context.... but only on *some* computers. It worked just fine on the machine I built it on... but not on some other people's machines. It's NOT a VBE Reference issue; the DLL exists, and none of the calls in the module rely on a VBE Reference. I've tried several other "providers..." no good. All zeros.

Here's the code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const MS_STRONG_PROV = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" 
Private Const PROV_RSA_FULL = 1 Private Const CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = 0



#If VBA7 Then

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" _
        (ByRef phProv As Long, ByVal pszContainer As String, ByVal pszProvider As String, _
        ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Boolean '

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptGenRandom Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal dwLen As Long, ByRef pbBuffer As Byte) As Boolean

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByRef hProv As Long, ByVal dwFlagas As Long)

#Else

    Private Declare Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" _
        (ByRef phProv As Long, ByVal pszContainer As String, ByVal pszProvider As String, _
        ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Boolean '

    Private Declare Function CryptGenRandom Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal dwLen As Long, ByRef pbBuffer As Byte) As Boolean

    Private Declare Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByRef hProv As Long, ByVal dwFlagas As Long)

#End If



Public Function RandomByte() As Byte

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim lngContext As Long, bytResult As Byte

    ' Supposed to dump a value into lngContext... only spitting out zero.
    Call CryptAcquireContext(lngContext, vbNullString, MS_STRONG_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)

    ' Which means THIS ALSO spits out only a zero....
    Call CryptGenRandom(lngContext, 1, bytResult)

    '...and this is crashing for unknown reasons.
    Call CryptReleaseContext(lngContext, 0)

    RandomByte = bytResult

End Function
```

Comment: Your API declarations are incorrect.  If you use `Long` instead of `LongPtr` for pointer variables, it will fail in a 64 bit execution context.

Comment: It works just fine on *my* 64-bit machine...

Comment: Have you checked to see what the return values are when it fails?  You're currently just discarding them. Also, is your Access installation 32bit?

Comment: Functions are only returning True or False.  On MY 64-bit machine, Access 2013/32-bit, I get True and it works (I get a random byte).  On another 64-bit machine, Access 2010/32-bit, I get False... and no random byte.  Adding LongPtr's didn't change anything either.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, have you tried calling GetLastError when they fail.

Comment: First one fails with -2146893802

Comment: Keyset does not exist.....

Comment: [This link may help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11507961/4088852).  I'd still change `hProv` to `LongPtr` - if it's worked so far, it's a fluke.  [`HCRYPTPROV`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382471(v=vs.85).aspx) is defined as `ULONG_PTR`, so you're only getting half of the handle if it's 64 bit.

Comment: I'll check further into these.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to initialize a key container, like so:

```
Private Const CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = 8

Call CryptAcquireContext(lngContext, vbNullString, MS_STRONG_PROV, _
PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET )
```

Then the other call (using `CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT`) works.

The full module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const MS_STRONG_PROV = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider"
Private Const PROV_RSA_FULL = 1
Private Const CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = 0
Private Const CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = 8

#If VBA7 Then

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" _
    (ByRef phProv As LongPtr, ByVal pszContainer As String, ByVal pszProvider As String, _
    ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Boolean '

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptGenRandom Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, ByVal dwLen As Long, ByRef pbBuffer As Byte) As Boolean

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByRef hProv As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlagas As Long)

#Else

  Private Declare Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" _
    (ByRef phProv As Long, ByVal pszContainer As String, ByVal pszProvider As String, _
    ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Boolean '

  Private Declare Function CryptGenRandom Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal dwLen As Long, ByRef pbBuffer As Byte) As Boolean

  Private Declare Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByRef hProv As Long, ByVal dwFlagas As Long)

#End If



Public Function RandomByte() As Byte

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim lngContext As LongPtr, bytResult As Byte

    Call CryptAcquireContext(lngContext, vbNullString, MS_STRONG_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)

    If Err.LastDllError = -2146893802 Then

        Call CryptAcquireContext(lngContext, vbNullString, MS_STRONG_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET)

    End If

    Call CryptGenRandom(lngContext, 1, bytResult)

    Call CryptReleaseContext(lngContext, 0)

    RandomByte = bytResult

End Function
```